# The use of backspace character at the end of the string

Tags: c++, string, character

backspace escape character '\b' is used t bring the cursor one character back...so it must work like a backspace key on our keyboard.

```
cout<<"Learn c++\b!";
```

This gives normal expected result- Learn c+!

But when using \b as the last character

```
cout<<"Learn c++!\b";
```

The '!' is not erased
output-Learn c++!

Instead i have to use

```
cout<<"Learn c++!\b \b";
```

to get the output-Learn c++

Can anybody tell the reason for such behavior..?

Comment: I think you already answered yourself: "is used t bring the cursor one character back". It does not say that it replaces the letter there with something. It does not say that it does not do so either. Old terminals did it this way or that. The correct way to no output a character you do not want is by the way to ... you know... not output it. Please explain about what you want to achieve. I suspect that somewhere there is a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `so it must work like a backspace key` Only at the interactive console. If you redirect the standard output to a file, or if you pipe it into another program, all characters including `\b` will still be in the stream.

Comment: The reason is that the corresponding key on a typewriter moves the carriage back one step.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption:

> so it must work like a backspace key

is not correct. `\b` moves the cursor one character backwards. It does not delete any characters. In an interactive terminal that leads to the effect you observed.

```
std::cout << "Hello, world\b!\n";
```

This starts with printing `Hello, world`, then moves the cursor 1 step to the left, then prints `!` and moves to a new line, resulting in `Hello, worl!`.

```
std::cout << "Hello, world!\b\n";
```

This starts with printing `Hello, world!`, then moves the cursor 1 step to the left, then moves to a new line resulting in `Hello, world!`.

As the question comments already mentioned this overwriting effect only happens in a terminal. If you output to a file all the characters including the `\b` are preserved as is.